# DataGrid.SelectedItems MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I developed my UI on MVVM pattern and now stuck on getting SelectedItems. Could you please modify my XAML and provide sample how do I get them insde ViewModel class.

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl Name="ResultGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"  Height="295" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1041" ReadOnly="True">
                    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                        <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
                            <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                        </xcdg:TableflowView>
                    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Comment: do you just want to get the selecteditems or do you also want to set selecteditems from viewmodel? further more you wanna get the selecteditems when selection is made or just when a e.g. button command is invoked?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Attached behaviors to get/set SelectedItems to datagrid.

I was facing similar issue in Metro apps, So had to write it myself.

Below is the link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr

Though i had written for metro apps, the same solution can be adapted in WPF/Silverlight.

```
    public class MultiSelectBehavior : Behavior<ListViewBase>
        {
            #region SelectedItems Attached Property
            public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "SelectedItems",
                typeof(ObservableCollection<object>),
                typeof(MultiSelectBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<object>(), PropertyChangedCallback));

            #endregion

            #region private
            private bool _selectionChangedInProgress; // Flag to avoid infinite loop if same viewmodel is shared by multiple controls
            #endregion

            public MultiSelectBehavior()
            {
                SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            }

            public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
            {
                get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
                set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
            }

            protected override void OnAttached()
            {
                base.OnAttached();
                AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
            }

            protected override void OnDetaching()
            {
                base.OnDetaching();
                AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
            }

            private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler =  (s, e) => SelectedItemsChanged(sender, e);
                if (args.OldValue is ObservableCollection<object>)
                {
                    (args.OldValue as ObservableCollection<object>).CollectionChanged -= handler;
                }

                if (args.NewValue is ObservableCollection<object>)
                {
                    (args.NewValue as ObservableCollection<object>).CollectionChanged += handler;
                }
            }

            private static void SelectedItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (sender is MultiSelectBehavior)
                {
                    var listViewBase = (sender as MultiSelectBehavior).AssociatedObject;

                    var listSelectedItems = listViewBase.SelectedItems;
                    if (e.OldItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                        {
                            if (listSelectedItems.Contains(item))
                            {
                                listSelectedItems.Remove(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (e.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                        {
                            if (!listSelectedItems.Contains(item))
                            {
                                listSelectedItems.Add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (_selectionChangedInProgress) return;
                _selectionChangedInProgress = true;
                foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
                {
                    if (SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                    {
                        SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
                {
                    if (!SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                    {
                        SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                _selectionChangedInProgress = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more to do if you want a multiselection and you want to get those selected items. Do you want to store the selected items and when some action is performed (button clicked or something like that) you want to use those selectedItems and do something with them?

There is a good example on that available here:

[Get SelectedItems From DataGrid Using MVVM](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.de/2011/07/get-selecteditems-from-datagrid-using.html)

It states it is designed for Silverlight, but it will work in WPF with MVVM too.

Perhaps this is a more straightforward approach:

[Get Selected items in a WPF datagrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/119505/Get-Selected-items-in-a-WPF-datagrid)

Answer (score -1):

Creating an attached behavior for wiring up every Read Only Collection or non Dependency property would take a significant amount of work. A simple solution is to pass the reference to the view model using the view.

```vb
Private ReadOnly Property ViewModel As MyViewModel
    Get
        Return DirectCast(DataContext, MyViewModel)
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub MyView_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    If ViewModel.SelectedItems Is Nothing Then
        ViewModel.SelectedItems = MyDataGrid.SelectedItems 
    End If
End Sub
```